# How to set access permission for a new user in Cognos namespace?

Tags: cognos

## Goal

I have created a new user, and I want to set his access permission to read so that he can only read the report but cannot edit it.

## Problem

Under the Permissions tab, I don't see the permission option for the new user (Jeff Waters), instead, I see the permission option for the **Directory Administrators**. How can I change the permission for this new user?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place.  Your screen capture shows you trying to set permissions for the user.  (Who can make changes to the user?)  What you need to set is permissions for the report.

Go to the report, right-click, Properties | Permissions.

Comment: Thank you. For my understanding, if I change a user's permission to Read, does that mean no other user can make any changes to that user?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you mean, "In the screen capture provided, if I change Directory Administrators permission on the Jeff Waters user to Read, does that mean no one make changes to Jeff Waters?"  The answer to that, I think, is, "No."  The system administrator (with implicit "Full" permission everywhere) can still make changes.  But changing permissions to edit users is a very specific use case.  I doubt you will ever need to do that.  Focus on permissions on reports, folders, report views, dashboards, and such.